# Pass variable from layout to view in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to pass a variable from the master layout to the view, but I'm having no luck.

**layout.phtml**

`$this->hadMessages = true;`

**myview.phtml**

`var_dump($this->hadMessages);`

The `var_dump` always comes back with `NULL`. From what I've read, the layout is a view too, so it should be in the same context, right?

I'm using Zend Framework 1.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout is rendered after the view, so that's why this doesn't work. Depending on what you are trying to do you might be able to achieve the desired effect with the help of a controller plugin.

Comment: Whaaaat? *After* the view? Is this some kind of reverse logic voodoo stuff? Makes absolutely no sense (at least not at first sight), but OK, so be it. I'm doing some decision making in the layout (can't move it to the controller), and I want to know inside the view if the layout showed any messages. Would that be possible in any way (maybe a partial would help -- when are partials rendered?). Thanks!

Comment: There are a number of advantages to rendering the layout after the view, e.g. the view can add `<script>` tags to the header, or manipulate the `headTitle()` or `headMeta()` helpers. Moving the logic to a controller plugin (not to a controller), still probably sounds like the right move for your use case. How are the messages assigned to the view?

Comment: By session (I'm building a nicer version of the `FlashMessenger` helper). So I'm calling `$flashmessenger->hasMessages()` in the layout and want to store it in a variable for later use in the view.

Comment: Can you not do the `hasMessages()` check in the view?

Comment: I can, but then I'd have to do it in every view, and I don't really want to duplicate my code that many times.

Comment: Ended up extending the built-in FlashMessenger and adding on top of that. It was a little smarter than me, I now get how it works. Going to accept your answer since it answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass variable from layout to view, because according to MVC pattern you shouldn't have tasks like this. Wether layout contains some messages or not should be decided on controller or bootstrap level, not in layout itself.
It means in controller you should make all needed assignments like `$this->view->layout_messages_shown = true` and get this variable value both in layout and view like `echo ( $this->layout_messages_shown ? "messages shown" : "messages hidden" )`